AMP Mismatch Error - Why is another domain set as my AMP in Search Console?
A few days ago, I received an email notifying me that an unknown user gained access to my Search Console using an unused token. Since then, I’ve been experiencing various errors, and my pages have started disappearing from Google search results.
One of the errors is an AMP mismatch.
We don’t have this unknown URL in our source code, and I’d like to know where this script is coming from.
Additionally, this text: ‘Link Situs Slot Gacor 2024 Resmi Terpercaya Hari Ini Dengan …’ is appearing in search results, even though it doesn’t exist in our source code
